Unit problem: $\rm N/cm$ or $\rm N/m$
Is that really wrong to solve a simple Hooke’s law equation which gave Force in N and displacement in cm to find out the spring constant in N/cm? The problem I was attempting to solve did not specify which units to use at all.

$\mathrm{N},\mathrm{m}^{-1}$ and $\mathrm{N},\mathrm{cm}^{-1}$ are both fine units to use for a spring constant. Generally we may prefer coherent units (e.g. $\mathrm{N},\mathrm{m}^{-1}$ in SI), but it really is not so important.

@RileyScottJacob Yes that's what I think if not stated explicitly it is right mathematically and physically .Thanks a lot.

$~F=k,x~$ $~k=\frac Fx,=\frac{N}{x}=\frac{kg,m}{s^2,x}~$ thus unit of x is m

It is not exactly wrong to express the spring constant in newtons per centimetre rather than  newtons per metre, but it is possible that in an exam you would lose marks for not using SI units in your answer.
